# Produce hierarchical dataset in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table of ID values of users column A has the management users and column B has the users. I want to be able to display a list of user that manage other users, for example.

```
User 1 can manage user 2
User 1 can manage user 3
User 3 can manage user 4
User 5 can manage user 6
```

This produces the following table:

```
--------------------------
|  mgtuserId  |  userId  |
--------------------------
|     1       |     2    |
|     1       |     3    |
|     3       |     4    |
|     5       |     6    |
--------------------------
```

I would like to have a query or stored procedure that returns the list of management users by following them down the hierarchical structure. So that if you are user 1 the following list will be output.

```
 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Then if you are user 2 then you will only have 2 output.

```
 2
```

Then if you are user 5 the following list is output and so on.

```
 5, 6
```

What is the best way to achieve this given that I have each users Id.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace YOUR_TABLE on your table name

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE get_users(IN base INT UNSIGNED)
BEGIN
DECLARE ids TEXT DEFAULT '';

SET @parents = base;
SET ids = base;

loop1: LOOP
    SET @stm = CONCAT(
        'SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(userId) INTO @parents FROM YOUR_TABLE',
        ' WHERE mgtuserId IN (', @parents, ')'
    );

    PREPARE fetch_childs FROM @stm;
    EXECUTE fetch_childs;
    DROP PREPARE fetch_childs;

    IF @parents IS NULL THEN LEAVE loop1; END IF;

    SET ids = CONCAT(ids, ',', @parents);
END LOOP;

SET @stm = CONCAT('(SELECT mgtuserId FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE mgtuserId=',base,') UNION (SELECT userId FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE userId IN (',ids, '))');

PREPARE fetch_childs FROM @stm;
EXECUTE fetch_childs;
DROP PREPARE fetch_childs;
END;
```

checking

```
CALL get_users(1);
1
2
3
4
```

and set in my.ini

```
thread_stack = 256K
```

Answer (score 0):

To give you some search terms: you are looking for the transitive closure of your relation, which requires recursive queries. To my knowledge, recusrive queries cannot be expressed in MySQL except with the help of stored procedures or functions.

Using some of the above terms in [a search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D%20transitive%20closure%20recursive&submit=search) will give you a large number of questions and answers closely related to yours. [how to work with recursive query in MySql?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8561654/1468366) is one of them. The answer there links to [a document](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/mysqlbook/sampler/mysqled1ch20.html) which describes a `PROCEDURE recursivesubtree` that might be a good starting point for your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The specification for your output leads to a slightly different version of what I do.

Assuming that you don't have any "loops", and don't have any rows where mgtuserId = userId, you can emulate a hierarchical query N levels deep by joining the table to itself multiple times, like this:

```
SELECT n0.userId AS n0_userId
     , n1.userId AS n1_userId
     , n2.userId AS n2_userId
     , n3.userId AS n3_userId
     , n4.userId AS n4_userId
     , n5.userId AS n5_userId
     , n6.userId AS n6_userId
  FROM mytable n0
  LEFT JOIN mytable n1 ON n1.mgtuserId = n0.userId
  LEFT JOIN mytable n2 ON n2.mgtuserId = n1.userId
  LEFT JOIN mytable n3 ON n3.mgtuserId = n2.userId
  LEFT JOIN mytable n4 ON n4.mgtuserId = n3.userId
  LEFT JOIN mytable n5 ON n5.mgtuserId = n4.userId
  LEFT JOIN mytable n6 ON n6.mgtuserId = n5.userId
 WHERE n0.userId = 1
```

But this query doesn't return the result set you specified, a comma separated list.

Each row this query returns represents a "path" down the tree, from the specified starting point to each leaf node (or, in this case, to every node that is no more than six levels deep (below the specified starting point).

No, it's not pretty. But you can see how this can be extended to N levels.

Right now, I don't see a good way to convert this to the result set you specified.

I may have to do the same kind of thing, but getting each level with a separate query (one level deep, two levels deep, etc.) and then using a UNION ALL to combine them. But that will be even uglier.

To get an unspecified number of levels down to each leaf node, we'd really need to use a temporary table, and do this same type of query iteratively. But of course, that's not a single query.

(I will work on a solution that returns your specified resultset.)