# Suggest SQL Query to retrieve all leaf nodes from Adjacency List Model

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have got a table structure in mysql like this:

```
  ________________________
 |  id      | int(auto)   |     
 |------------------------|   
 |  name    | varchar     |
 |------------------------|
 |  link    | varchar     |
 |------------------------|
 | parent_id| int         |
 |________________________|
```

Basically it is a design for a database driven menu, the root menu has `parent_id` 0, whereas child menu have their root menu specified on `parent_id` field. It can be up to 3-4 level.

Now, I need to find all child menu under a root menu. I can easily do that for one level menu, but I can't traverse behind that. I can do that by writing a program (by merging resultsets), but it will be much easier and convenient way, if I can do that using just SQL.

I can't change any structure of the table or otherwise modify the system. Please help.

Comment: There's a good reason this sort of data is usually stored in a different manner. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

Comment: read this http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: Thanks. The article is really helpful. Specially 'Retrieving a Full Tree from Adjacency List Model' was too close to my answer, however instead of diving them on levels, I need to consolidate on a single row. Is it possible.

Comment: I [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11749862/1468366) a very similar question today, that might help. Once you've worked out how you want to deal with this, you should probably write your own answer.

Comment: Thanks MvG. Writing a procedure seems to be the only way to get what I want. I am working on it. The only problem is most of the web host don't support MySQL procedures or they simply don't allow to change MySQL parameters. I will try with procedure first, but if I can't mange to use that due to restriction, I will simply merge those resultset using program. Now, the advantage is I don't have to query multiple times, but just one time, thanks to mikehyller article. Whatever it is, I will post my approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the following query to get all the child menu id (comma separated) of a root menu (in this query it is 2). It can support upto 3 levels. I know the query is not optimized and got performance issue, but still I think it is the only way to achieve the solution, without using procedure(which I can't use).

```
select group_concat(lev0) from 
(select concat_ws(',',lev2,group_concat(lev3)) as lev0 from 
(SELECT  t2.id as lev2, 
t3.id as lev3, 
t4.id as lev4
FROM menus AS t1
LEFT JOIN menus AS t2 ON t2.parent_id = t1.id
LEFT JOIN menus AS t3 ON t3.parent_id = t2.id
LEFT JOIN menus AS t4 ON t4.parent_id = t3.id
WHERE t1.id = '2') t0 group by lev2) t;
```

Comment: Hey, man! Can you please help me out here? Can you tell me how to union this query into one column instead of concat'ing commas?

Answer (score 1):

This will give you all the parents with their childs:

```
SELECT t1.name AS parentName, t1.Link AS parentLink
 t2.name AS childName, t2.link AS childLink
FROM table t1
 LEFT OUTER JOIN table t2 ON (t2.parent_id = t1.id)
```

If you don't want the root level:

```
SELECT t1.name AS parentName, t1.Link AS parentLink
 t2.name AS childName, t2.link AS childLink
FROM table t1
 INNER JOIN table t2 ON (t2.parent_id = t1.id)
```

Comment: I don't need to list all nodes and their subnodes, but all level of subnodes of any particular node.

Comment: This query does not appear to work for multiple sibling nodes.