# SQL select all products from specified category and its childrens

Tags: mysql, sql, parent-child

I have db like this:

```
categories(id, parent_id)
items(id, category_id)
```

And have those entries:

Categories:

```
Paintings(id=1, parent_id=NULL), 
Landscape(id=2, parent_id=1)
```

Items:

```
Painting1(id=1, category_id=2)
```

I am trying to fetch all of the Items from a specified category.

For example: all items from Paintings will be items from `Paintings`, `Landscape` and any category that has as a parent `Paintings`.

I am trying to execute this:

```
SELECT * FROM items p
JOIN categories cp ON p.category_id = cp.id
JOIN categories cc ON cc.parent_id = cp.id AND p.category_id = cc.id
WHERE cp.id = "1"
```

But it doesn't work how I expected.

Comment: You have joined categories table twice. I think you want to use Items table in last join

Comment: Home many levels can you have? I mean, you could have another category having parent_id=2; and this behaviour could go on. I think you won't solve it with a plain query, but with something recursive...

Comment: Can you have many levels of category (eg. Painting1 belongs to "Rural Landscapes" which belongs to "Landscapes" which belongs to "Paintings"), or only top level and category (ie. "Paintings" and "Landscapes")? If the former, note that MySQL doesn't allow recursive queries - see more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561654/how-to-work-with-recursive-query-in-mysql

Comment: I'm going to have only main parent and chilren categories. For example: There won't be any category which has as a parent Landscape.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM items p
JOIN categories cp ON p.category_id = cp.id
JOIN categories cc ON cp.parent_id = cc.id
WHERE cc.id = "1"
```

Comment: It works when I select items from category which has parent category. But it doesn't when I select items from which doesn't have parent. For example from landscape.