# Loop through MySQL database until field = 'specified value'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops, pdo

I need some help please! Basically I have a system that has an unlimited amount of categories and the way in which it works is through unique IDs. So basically the system will find the root folder and match all subfolders based on its parent's UID. An endless loop...

But now I want to do the opposite of that in a single MySQL statement (if possible).

Basically I want it to do this.. (By the way this isn't my actual code, it's just how I want it to work)

```
SELECT UID FROM Table
WHERE UID = 'value'
--AND ALSO:
SELECT * FROM SameTable
WHERE UID = The Parent UID just fetched...
```

And do this until the UID = 'Specified Value'.

I seriously hope that makes sense!

Is it even possible? I could do it using multiple queries in a PHP loop I know, but that just feels like a long way around, and bad practice.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. Do you want a path to the root of the filesystem or a path from the selected node to all leaves?

Comment: A path to the root please. Basically, the reason for it is I'm going to create a search function which is easily found... But I need to find its path back to the root.

Comment: You need one query for each level till you reach the root. You could look into optimizing your data structure for these kinds of lookups.

Comment: Ahh ok. That's what I feared. I just know SQL is pretty powerful, and I definitely don't take advantage of its power. Now I need that bit of extra power, it doesn't seem to be able to handle my need. 

Typical! Thanks anyway.

Comment: How powerful it is depends on your model. If you have very unrelational data SQL isn't going to do much for you. Trees are one form of unrelational data.

Comment: If you have in the table ID and ParentID then you can use CTE. link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561654/how-to-work-with-recursive-query-in-mysql

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the hierarchy path for a tree representation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15584013/how-to-find-the-hierarchy-path-for-a-tree-representation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is called "Hierarchical data". You have to read on it on google. In short, there are three main ways to represent it in a 2-dimensional table:

- Adjacency list (what you have). You scarcely can make it with single query
- Materialized path (my favorite). Natural and readable. Not so efficient though.
- Nested set (Most complicated) yet most powerful.

You can choose any system you like ir stick to your current one. Single query is not Holy grail to pursue at any cost.