# INNER JOIN table on itself

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, inner-join

I have a table which represents friendships between two users. Each entry is unidirectional; a friendship requires two entries to be represented. I would like to keep it this way.

```
user1_id | user2_id 
   43        44
   44        43
```

I'm curious what the best way to query against this kind of setup is. For example, how would query for a list of all friends of a particular user?

The solution I've come up with is to invert and inner join the friendships table onto itself, to get a list of all complete pairs first, then use a normal WHERE clause:

```
SELECT f.user2_id 
    FROM friendships f
        INNER JOIN friendships f2
            ON f.user1_id = f2.user2_id 
            && f.user2_id = f2.user1_id
        WHERE f.user1_id = 43;
```

To get into a juicier situation, I would also need to be able to query to get a list of threads created by friends of a user. I'm still adjusting to the abstract thinking required to work with joins, but the solution I've come up with is this:

```
SELECT thread_id,owner_id,message,time  
    FROM threads th                             
        INNER JOIN friendships f                                
            ON th.owner_id = f.user2_id                             
            && f.user1_id = 43                           
        INNER JOIN friendships f2                               
            ON f.user2_id = f2.user1_id                             
            && f.user1_id = f2.user2_id
```

This seems to work, but I'm testing it on a very empty database. Since my grasp on joins is still a little weak, I'm afraid that there are situations in which this will come back with bad results. So my questions are:

1. Are these two queries behaving as I expect them to?
2. Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: I don't know if i understood correctly. Do you want to do this - SELECT [uid1],[uid2]
FROM [Friends]
ORDER BY [uid1]--or WHERE [uid1] = 43

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you're asking, but the ORDER BY statement shouldn't be coming into play here, no. I just want a list all users which from a complete friendship pair with user #43.

Comment: In the first query your solution will give you only *user2*, but with join the second condition (f.user2_id = f2.user1_id) is useless - you are listing only user1. I think it could me made with **UNION**. Also with **OR** but will be very slow. And the second for me is fine.

Comment: What you are describing is a [recursive join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_join). Recursive joins are not implemented in MySQL; you either have to change databases (e.g. to PostgreSQL) or change your data to [non-recursive relations](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/mysqlbook/sampler/mysqled1ch20.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to work with recursive query in MySql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561654/how-to-work-with-recursive-query-in-mysql)

Comment: @DourHighArch I don't believe that's true. This relationship is not recursive. A friendship is represented by exactly two rows, which are unidirectional relationships. There is no implied hierarchy and no iterations or loops should be required to query them, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @nathan - I tried your query. It gives me incorrect results. Add more sample rows to your table. I will add the query to your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's start to answer this question by creating a query which gives a list of all (user, friend) pairs.  You've required that a friend pair be a reciprocal relationship, so we need to do that.  Otherwise the `friendships` table would offer those pairs.

Your query is pretty close.  What you need for this query is the inner join.

```
SELECT f1.user1_id AS user, 
       f1.user2_id AS friend 
  FROM friendships AS f1
  JOIN friendships f2 
    ON  (f1.user1_id = f2.user2_id AND f1.user2_id = f2.user1_id)
```

Then, you can employ this query as a virtual table. For example, you can do this to get a list of the friends of user 43.

```
 SELECT friend
   FROM (
        SELECT f1.user1_id AS user, 
               f1.user2_id AS friend 
          FROM friendships AS f1
          JOIN friendships f2 
            ON  (f1.user1_id = f2.user2_id AND f1.user2_id = f2.user1_id)
        ) AS friends 
  WHERE user = 43
```

You might want to set your friends query up as a view, like so.

```
 CREATE VIEW friends AS (
        SELECT f1.user1_id AS user, 
               f1.user2_id AS friend 
          FROM friendships AS f1
          JOIN friendships f2 
            ON  (f1.user1_id = f2.user2_id AND f1.user2_id = f2.user1_id)
 )
```

That way you can abbreviate your complex queries like this.

```
 SELECT friend FROM friends WHERE user = 43;
```

Your juicier queries get easy too:

```
SELECT thread_id,owner_id,message,time  
  FROM threads AS th
  JOIN (
        SELECT f1.user1_id AS user, 
               f1.user2_id AS friend 
          FROM friendships AS f1
          JOIN friendships f2 
            ON  (f1.user1_id = f2.user2_id AND f1.user2_id = f2.user1_id)

       ) AS f ON th.owner_id = f.friend
 WHERE f.user = 43
```

If you use the view you can do this. It means the same thing but is easier to read.

```
SELECT thread_id,owner_id,message,time  
  FROM threads AS th
  JOIN friends AS f ON th.owner_id = f.friend
 WHERE f.user = 43
```

(Note: `JOIN` and `INNER JOIN` are synonymous.)

See how that goes? You can encapsulate your `friends` query (either as a view or just inline as a virtual table) and use its results.  The optimizer knows how to do this quickly when you specify such things as `WHERE f.user = 43`.

If you have lots of rows in the `friendships` table you may find that a pair of compound indexes `(user1_id, user2_id)` and `(user2_id, user1_id)` help the performance of these queries

(It's not a recursive query, comments to the contrary notwithstanding.)

Comment: Fantastic answer. I was totally unaware of the existence of views, and this also helped better my understanding of query encapsulation techniques in general. Thanks for the detailed response!

Comment: Another new SQL developer "gets" the *structured* in *structured query language!* Hooray.

Comment: Just to point out for posterity, you did use both 'AND' and '&&' operators in a few places. I don't believe you meant to do that.